# How can I add a column to specific position in Athena exists table by Python script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, aws-glue, amazon-athena, aws-glue-data-catalog

I am trying to create a python script that gets a column name and data type and add them to a specific position in the Athena table (For example, see pic below).
I know it can be done by Glue - Data catalog - Edit schema;

[image: Glow - Data catalog - Edit schema]

I read all the documentation on this subject but did not find any practical solution.
I also checked Python packages - [awsglue](https://pypi.org/project/awsglue-local/) and [pyathena](https://pypi.org/project/pyathena/).

1. Is it possible?
2. Is there a way to get a schema output (In the form of JSON or similar) as seen in Glue - Data catalog?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the [boto3 package](https://pypi.org/project/boto3/):

> Boto3 is the Amazon Web Services (AWS) Software Development Kit (SDK) for Python, which allows Python developers to write software that makes use of services like Amazon S3 and Amazon EC2.

In particular, you need to look into [`update_table`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue.html#Glue.Client.update_table):

> Updates a metadata table in the Data Catalog.

You can specify the columns in the `StorageDescriptor` dictionary within `TableInput`. The easiest for your request would be most likely using [`get_table`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue.html#Glue.Client.get_table) to get the current table definition then manipulate it and then use `update_table` to update it.